# Iteratively accessing all binary tree nodes?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have a Binary Tree which has a word on each node.

In another Class I need to access the nodes one by one and then manipulate the words. What is the best way to access the nodes one by one from another class?

In my BinaryTree Class each node has a leftchild, rightchild and a value(String). I have three methods, printinorder, insert and findnode. The find node takes in a string and sees if that string is stored in any of the node values.

```
public void printInOrder(Node node) {
    if (node != null) {
        printInOrder(node.left);
        System.out.println(node.value);
        printInOrder(node.right);
    }
```

I have another class and need to get at the nodes one by one but I am not sure whats the best way of doing it from another class. I am able to traverse the tree from within the class but not from a different class.

Comment: We need to see more code to give you a meaningful answer.  Can you post your binary tree class?

Comment: will update the question.

Comment: You need to give way more context.  What can you change?  What can't you change?  What fields are public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read templatetypedef's answer, which is a more efficient approach. The advantage of the approach I present is that it does not require any changes to your existing Node class, and uses the same pattern you've already used for PrintInOrder. It only relies upon public properties of the Node class, so should be useable from a separate class.

```
public List<Node> nodes GetAllNodes(Node root) {
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    if (root != null) {
        nodes.addAll(GetAllNodes(root.left));
        nodes.add(root);
        nodes.addAll(GetAllNodes(root.right));
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

I didn't compile or test this, so there may be errors.

Comment: yes my eye-compiler tells me, unmatched `)` , semicolons are missing. :D

Comment: Forgetting semicolons has been a byproduct of writing a lot of Python today. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

One way to walk over all the nodes in a binary tree is to do the following, which starts the leftmost node and repeatedly migrates to the current node's **[inorder successor](http://facultyfp.salisbury.edu/despickler/personal/Resources/AdvancedDataStructures/Handouts/succ_pred_rules.pdf)**:

1. Start by walking as far to the left as you possibly can without falling off the tree.  This is your first node.
2. To get from one node to the next one that should be visited, do the following:

   1. If the node has a right child, descend to the right child, then continuously descend to the left child as far as possible.  You end at the next node to visit.
   2. Otherwise, repeatedly walk upward from the node to its parent until you walk up an edge from a left child to its parent.  Where you end up is the new node.

This ends up taking only O(n) time across all nodes, so it's a very fast way to migrate between nodes.

In order for this to work, you will either need to have each node store a parent pointer or will have to maintain a stack of the path of nodes from the start node downward to the current node.  However, for reasonably balanced trees, this is much more space efficient than populating an entire list of the nodes in the tree and returning it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a tree class, write first a method that traverses the tree first (breadth/depth search). At every node in the traversal, assuming your nodes are some type of object that holds a word in one of its variables, access the node and change the stored word. Basically write functions in your Binary Tree class that let you do this, and call them in your other class.

Comment: Thanks. I need to manipulate the code from another class. So ideally have some code in the BinaryTree class that returns the node one by one to the other class. But from my understanding this is not possible.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to do that you think isn't possible? It may be.

Comment: Sorry, I am always bad at explaining things. I have two class, BinaryTree and Dictionary. In the Dictionary Class I need to get A word from the BinaryTree Class and compare it to another word (complex comparision which is 30 lines long) and then get the second word from the tree and do the comparision again. At the moment I have all the words stored in a file and I just read in the file line by line in a while loop. (While Line != null) However, I need to use a binary tree to store the words.

Comment: That is all possible, which part of what you described above is giving you trouble?

Comment: Its returning the value of one node to the other class but doing so in a loop thats the problem. For example, I can easily return one node to the other class, but I am unsure how to keep track of which nodes I have already accessed in order to get the next node.

Comment: If you are allowed to, a simple fix would be simply adding another field to your Binary Tree class like a boolean alreadyVisited, and making it True if you did. You can then modify your function that returns nodes to return node if !alreadyVisited

Answer (score 0):

For searching :

You could sort your tree to a binary search tree. Or when you were building the tree, build a binary search tree. It would be the best way to search. `O(logn)` .

The search should be implemented in your `findNode(String value)` method

or you have problem to implement the search?

Comment: Thanks for the tip but my search method works well at the moment.

Comment: @Vuzuggu on which method do you have problem? I thought it was findNode... what is your problem?? I get lost...

Comment: In my other class I have a method. Which currently reads in a words from a file (one word per line) It then compares this word with an inputted word based on vowels and constants etc. It is a while (line != null) {do the comparision br.readline()} I need to change it so it doesn't access the words from the file but instead fro the binary tree

Comment: @Vuzuggu so you want to check if user input word exists in your tree? it is a search problem right? search != traverse the whole tree. if you have right data-structure.